# rails re-enable stuck jobs in delayed_job

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I've been implementing delayed_job gem(mysql version) for some time now, and situation
Trouble is some tasks seem to be stuck and they fail to execute.
example:

> id, priority, attempts,  run_at, created_at, updated_at
>   '8', '0', '0', '2015-01-15 15:32:45', '2015-01-15 15:32:42',  '2015-01-15 15:32:42'
>   //Time according to my timezone

I use mysql workbench to run this simple script

> UPDATE delayed_jobs
>    SET
>    run_at = NOW() + interval 1 minute,
>    created_at = NOW(),
>    updated_at = NOW();

I start delayed job on the server via ssh

> $ RAILS_ENV=pre_prod bin/delayed_job -i=43 run
>   delayed_job.=43: process with pid 6407 started.

Nothing happens, jobs are still populating mysql table....
How can i relaunch these tasks ?
Can you help me ?

Comment: I usually only set `run_at` at `Time.now`

Comment: Sadly enough this didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough the problem was in different timezones  on DB server and server that application is ran on ...